# Why is SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync in Asp.Net identity returning false?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

Reached wits end with this.

I'm trying to automate the process of two factor authentication in Asp.Net identity so that we don't challenge users for a security code every time.

Currently, the code looks like this:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    // other cases
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        int challengeFrequency = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChallengeFrequency"]);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        if (rnd.Next(1, challengeFrequency + 1) == 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { returnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        else
        {
            var token = await UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, "Phone Code");
            await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync();
            await SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Phone Code", token, false, false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
}
```

Which is - as far as I can see - the same sequence of function calls used in the process of sending a user an SMS call.

In my code the token is generated, but then the call to `SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync()` seems to behave erratically. Sometimes it returns true and the user is signed in as desired. Other times it returns false and the sign-in fails. Occasionally it returns null and the sign-in fails.

Documentation on this method seems extremely sparse. Can anyone *please* help with this? I cannot find a way into this problem at all.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Jalal I did, but I'm afraid I don't recall what it was. I do remember that to fix it, I downloaded the source code - https://github.com/aspnet/Identity - added it to the project and stepped through to see exactly what was going on.